# LDAP: Querying all Users of all Groups in an OU

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I got an AD-Structure where all Users are distributed across multiple OUs that are part of the Base OU. (OU=Baseou,DC=x,DC=x)

Within one specific OU (OU=GroupOU,OU=BaseOU,DC=x,DC=x) there are multiple groups.

I need to query all Users that are member of those groups, without specifying every group manually.

Is there an easy way to do this with a filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this with a single LDAP query. I thought this might work:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(memberOf=*OU=GroupOU,OU=BaseOU,DC=x,DC=x))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Even if it did, it would be very inefficient and would not include domain local groups.

You're better off querying all the groups first, then going through the groups and querying the members.

In PowerShell, for example, it would look something like this:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=GroupOU,OU=BaseOU,DC=x,DC=x" | Get-ADGroupMember
```